# Trouble adding item to a java linked list

Tags: java, linked-list

The last part of this program should be adding the pickles item between the lettuce and chicken item, but whenever I run it it adds it to the end of the list. I have no idea why. Is this a problem with the way I'm outputting it? I honestly have no idea why this is happening. Please help!

```
public class LinkedListDemo 
{
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {

List<String> myLinkedList = new LinkedList<String>();

String strOutput="";

myLinkedList.add("Bread1");
myLinkedList.add("mustard");
myLinkedList.add("lettuce");
myLinkedList.add("chicken");
myLinkedList.add("tomato");
myLinkedList.add("Bread2");

ListIterator<String> lit = myLinkedList.listIterator();
while(lit.hasNext()) 
{
  strOutput +=(lit.next() + ", ");
}
strOutput +=("end...\n");    


while(lit.hasPrevious()) 
{
  strOutput +=(lit.previous() + ", ");
}
strOutput +=("end...\n");


lit.next();
lit.next();
lit.next();

myLinkedList.add("pickles");

ListIterator<String> lit2 = myLinkedList.listIterator();

while(lit2.hasNext()) 
{
  strOutput +=(lit2.next() + ", ");
}
strOutput +=("end...\n");    

javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, strOutput);
System.exit(0);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your list is separate from the iterator in the sense that the state of the iterator isn't reflected in the list itself. To add something using the iterator, [use the `add` method of the iterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#add(E)).

Comment: Ah, that is the source of my confusion! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

`myLinkedList.add("pickles");` will always add it in the end. It doesnot matter where the iterator is. They are both independent.

You should use: `myLinedList.add(3,"pickles")` to add it between "lettuce" and "chicken"

or

You can use the iterators `add` method to add it where ever you want. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#add(E)

Comment: That is also a good way to do it! Thanks to all of you for these very good responses! The rest of the program should be a snap.